# How to add sale_line_id field to all of the steps in delivery order?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

From what I understand, `sale_line_id` in `stock.move`model  is added on creation only on the delivery order. Suppose I have 3 steps: `pick`,`pack`,`out`. Only `out` has a value in `sale_line_id`. I would like to customize so that all of the steps contain `sale_line_id` value.

So, I would like to know which method in which model that I have to make an adjustment in order for it to contain `sale_line_id` field for other steps as well.

I tried tracking down the flow, which I am not quite familiar with.

I have looked into these method but couldn't find the right method to do it.

```
_action_launch_stock_rule
_run_pull
_get_stock_move_values
_get_custom_move_fields
```

**Update**

I just found out that `_action_launch_stock_rule` method is called from sale order lines to create procurements that have `sale_line_id`. However, I still can't find where the other steps that have no `sale_line_id` field are created.

**Stock Rule setup**

> PICK:
>
> action: pull
>
> procurement_method: make_to_stock
>
> PACK:
>
> action: pull
>
> procurement_method: make_to_order
>
> OUT:
>
> action: pull
>
> procurement_method: make_to_order

Note: I am not the one who configured this setup. I also don't know the reason why it is what it is.

Comment: You should look into the `stock` module, because `stock.move`s will create "procurements" when confirmed. So a starting point would be `stock.move._action_confirm()` or a bit later `stock.move._prepare_procurement_values()`.

Comment: Could you add the `stock.rule`s setup of your pick, pack and out steps? Because it depends on the setup of the used `procure_method` and very important the `action` in the rules.

Comment: @CZoellner I added the `stock.rule`'s setup into the question. This information make me understand the stock rule better too. I didn't know about this before.

Comment: `make_to_stock` is processing another way. It's seems that it is not making a procurement on the move's confirmation. Right now i don't know which way Odoo is creating the pick move :-/

Answer (score 1):

Here the process that update `stock_move` records to set `sale_line_id` using the `_prepare_procurement_values` method.
As @CZoellner said, you could inherit the model to append one entry in the returned dictionary of the def _prepare_procurement_values:

```py
class StockMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move'

    def _prepare_procurement_values(self):
        res = super()._prepare_procurement_values()
        res['sale_line_id']=self.id
        return res
```

in addons/stock/models/stock_move.py

```py
class StockMove(models.Model):
    name = 'stock.move'
...
    
    def _prepare_procurement_values(self):
        """ Prepare specific key for moves or other componenets that will be created from a stock rule
        comming from a stock move. This method could be override in order to add other custom key that could
        be used in move/po creation.
        """
        self.ensure_one()
        group_id = self.group_id or False
        if self.rule_id:
            if self.rule_id.group_propagation_option == 'fixed' and self.rule_id.group_id:
                group_id = self.rule_id.group_id
            elif self.rule_id.group_propagation_option == 'none':
                group_id = False
        product_id = self.product_id.with_context(lang=self._get_lang())
        return {
            'product_description_variants': self.description_picking and self.description_picking.replace(product_id._get_description(self.picking_type_id), ''),
            'date_planned': self.date,
            'date_deadline': self.date_deadline,
            'move_dest_ids': self,
            'group_id': group_id,
            'route_ids': self.route_ids,
            'warehouse_id': self.warehouse_id or self.picking_id.picking_type_id.warehouse_id or self.picking_type_id.warehouse_id,
            'priority': self.priority,
            'orderpoint_id': self.orderpoint_id,
        }

def _action_confirm(self, merge=True, merge_into=False):
        """ Confirms stock move or put it in waiting if it's linked to another move.
        :param: merge: According to this boolean, a newly confirmed move will be merged
        in another move of the same picking sharing its characteristics.
        """
        move_create_proc = self.env['stock.move']
        move_to_confirm = self.env['stock.move']
        move_waiting = self.env['stock.move']

        to_assign = {}
        for move in self:
            if move.state != 'draft':
                continue
            # if the move is preceeded, then it's waiting (if preceeding move is done, then action_assign has been called already and its state is already available)
            if move.move_orig_ids:
                move_waiting |= move
            else:
                if move.procure_method == 'make_to_order':
                    move_create_proc |= move
                else:
                    move_to_confirm |= move
            if move._should_be_assigned():
                key = (move.group_id.id, move.location_id.id, move.location_dest_id.id)
                if key not in to_assign:
                    to_assign[key] = self.env['stock.move']
                to_assign[key] |= move

        # create procurements for make to order moves
        procurement_requests = []
        for move in move_create_proc:
            values = move._prepare_procurement_values()
            origin = (move.group_id and move.group_id.name or (move.origin or move.picking_id.name or "/"))
            procurement_requests.append(self.env['procurement.group'].Procurement(
                move.product_id, move.product_uom_qty, move.product_uom,
                move.location_id, move.rule_id and move.rule_id.name or "/",
                origin, move.company_id, values))
        self.env['procurement.group'].run(procurement_requests, raise_user_error=not self.env.context.get('from_orderpoint'))

        move_to_confirm.write({'state': 'confirmed'})
        (move_waiting | move_create_proc).write({'state': 'waiting'})

        # assign picking in batch for all confirmed move that share the same details
        for moves in to_assign.values():
            moves._assign_picking()
        self._push_apply()
        self._check_company()
        moves = self
        if merge:
            moves = self._merge_moves(merge_into=merge_into)
        # call `_action_assign` on every confirmed move which location_id bypasses the reservation
        moves.filtered(lambda move: not move.picking_id.immediate_transfer and move._should_bypass_reservation() and move.state == 'confirmed')._action_assign()
        return moves
```

Using the dictionary returned by def _prepare_procurement_values, the creation of "stock.move" records is performed under specific conditions (rules...): in addons/stock/models/stock_rule.py

```py
    @api.model
    def run(self, procurements, raise_user_error=True):
        """Fulfil `procurements` with the help of stock rules.

        Procurements are needs of products at a certain location. To fulfil
        these needs, we need to create some sort of documents (`stock.move`
        by default, but extensions of `_run_` methods allow to create every
        type of documents).

        :param procurements: the description of the procurement
        :type list: list of `~odoo.addons.stock.models.stock_rule.ProcurementGroup.Procurement`
        :param raise_user_error: will raise either an UserError or a ProcurementException
        :type raise_user_error: boolan, optional
        :raises UserError: if `raise_user_error` is True and a procurement isn't fulfillable
        :raises ProcurementException: if `raise_user_error` is False and a procurement isn't fulfillable
        """

        def raise_exception(procurement_errors):
            if raise_user_error:
                dummy, errors = zip(*procurement_errors)
                raise UserError('\n'.join(errors))
            else:
                raise ProcurementException(procurement_errors)

        actions_to_run = defaultdict(list)
        procurement_errors = []
        for procurement in procurements:
            procurement.values.setdefault('company_id', procurement.location_id.company_id)
            procurement.values.setdefault('priority', '0')
            procurement.values.setdefault('date_planned', fields.Datetime.now())
            if (
                procurement.product_id.type not in ('consu', 'product') or
                float_is_zero(procurement.product_qty, precision_rounding=procurement.product_uom.rounding)
            ):
                continue
            rule = self._get_rule(procurement.product_id, procurement.location_id, procurement.values)
            if not rule:
                error = _('No rule has been found to replenish "%s" in "%s".\nVerify the routes configuration on the product.') %\
                    (procurement.product_id.display_name, procurement.location_id.display_name)
                procurement_errors.append((procurement, error))
            else:
                action = 'pull' if rule.action == 'pull_push' else rule.action
                actions_to_run[action].append((procurement, rule))

        if procurement_errors:
            raise_exception(procurement_errors)

        for action, procurements in actions_to_run.items():
            if hasattr(self.env['stock.rule'], '_run_%s' % action):
                try:
                    getattr(self.env['stock.rule'], '_run_%s' % action)(procurements)
                except ProcurementException as e:
                    procurement_errors += e.procurement_exceptions
            else:
                _logger.error("The method _run_%s doesn't exist on the procurement rules" % action)

        if procurement_errors:
            raise_exception(procurement_errors)
        return True
```

Comment: From what I tried, `_prepare_procurement_values` method will get `sale_line_id` when it is called in `sale_order_line` model, which calls only on `out` order. `pick` and `pack` orders will call `_prepare_procurement_values` in `stock.move` model, which does not have a way to access the designated sale order line. Can you point exactly where do I need to do the modification in order to get `sale_order_id` for `pick` and `pack`? The `procurements` input in `run` method already came in without `sale_line_id`.

Comment: Could u tell me please Which field or variable store the values out, pick and pack ?

Comment: @holydragon the calls on `stock.move._prepare_procurement_values()` have the calling move as `self` where `sale_line_id` should be set. You only have to add the sale_line_id to the values?

Comment: The `_prepare_procurement_values` in this answer is NOT the method i mean! Keep that in mind ;-)

Comment: you re right, i have corrected my answer accordingly

Comment: @CZoellner @Ahrimann I may not be correct, but what I got from using the method `_prepare_procurement_values` in the edited answer is an error "Record does not exist or has been deleted. (Record: sale.order.line(2329,), User: 1)". I suspect it is because you are using `stock.move`'s `id` to assign into `sale_line_id` that is `sale_order_line` model. I also inspect the `self` object to see if it has `sale_line_id` value, which it only has the value on `out` order, but not on the other steps. So, I cannot find the designated sale order line for that `stock.move` from `self` object in that method

Comment: Apart from that, the `_prepare_procurement_values` in `stock.move` only gets called for `out` and `pack` step. The `pick` step does not get into this method from what I tried to debug the `self` object. It came in only 2 times out of 3 steps.